# Объединить словари в один файл и почистить от дублей, чем?

Tags: сортировка, словари, awk, брутфорс, дублирование

Какая тулза может объединить несколько словарей в один файл после чего отсортировать и очистить от дублей ?

**100+** txt, dic, doc - словарей, более 300 Гб

От инструмента требуется поддержка UTF-8 и чтоб не удаляло пробелы в конце строки

Comment: например, программа sort. `$ sort -u файлы > результат` (файлы, естественно, должны быть текстовыми).

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin для моей задачи скорее `cat dict/*.* | sort | uniq > output.txt` но справиться ли он с таким большим объемом ?

В приоритете скорость выполнения

Comment: абсолютно ненужное увеличение процессов с одного (предложенного мной) до трёх (предложенных вами) процедуру точно не ускорит. а справится ли ваш диск с таким объёмом информации — вам виднее.

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin да, действительно, не знал что у `sort` есть параметр `-u`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

если это текстовые файлы, то программы *sort* вполне достаточно:

```
$ sort -u файл(ы) > результат
```

опция `-u` — «удалить дубликаты» («оставить только уникальные строки»).

---

по поводу требуемых ресурсов — можно ознакомиться с ответами на этот вопрос: [How could the UNIX sort command sort a very large file?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/930044/4827341)

кратко: используется [внешняя сортировка](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%88%D0%BD%D1%8F%D1%8F_%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0) (методом n-путевого слияния), а значит в файловой системе, где находится временный каталог (`$TMPDIR` или `/tmp` или явно указанный опцией `-T каталог`), должно быть (насколько я понимаю) **как минимум столько же** свободного места (для *временных файлов*), сколько занимают исходные данные.