# Как убрать повторяющуюся информацию в текстовом файле с помощью Bash?

Tags: bash

Есть файл, в котором содержится любая информация. К примеру ID чего-либо:

```
0001
0002
0003
0002
```

Как убрать повторяющиеся строке с помощью скрипта Bash?

Comment: некоторые (из многих) дубликаты: 1. [порядок не важен](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/968026/178576). 2. [порядок важен](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/537604/178576)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если порядок строк в результате не важен, то `sort -u <имя файла>`.

Comment: Да, но такой метод можно использовать с небольшим количеством данных. Когда в файле находится больше 10000 строк, то это неудобно. Суть такого скрипта должна заключаться в том, чтобы искать повторения, убирать их и сохранять файл.

Comment: @АрсенийТайко, почему не удобно? Сохранение в файл идет через `>`: `sort -u input.txt > output.txt`