# Как очистить дубли в текстовом документе? (444 ГБ)

Tags: windows, текст, txt

Как очистить дубли в текстовом документе? (444 ГБ)

Сортировка мне не обязательна, главное удалить дубликаты строк

Скорость обработки не важна, важен сам результат

На харде свободного столько же места, сколько и весит файл

Перепробовал множество вариантов, от gawk и до простых текстовых утилит, работающих от ОЗУ

Кто может подсказать какой-нибудь способ решения?

OS: Windows 10

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: а есть пример строчек? если там md5 хеши, то будет одно решение, если там строки разного размера - тогда другое.

Comment: Строки разные, как их длинна и вес, это логины и пароли с баз, вот пример

Duncan-Smith2656

Filotei8136
Nyberg3992
Patience5259
aleksgarashchenko
finarias1
gs67er
multiplikatiivisia
oleg.detka
omraaden7
tabbykalt

Comment: ок, не совсем понятно, но я бы делал в этом случае так. Если все начинается на буквы/цифры (в принципе, это можно один раз пробежаться и проверить), то просто берем последовательно две буквы aa и бежим по всему файлу и выписываем те строки, которые на них начинаются. Если слова распределены равномерно, то это будет уже десятки-сотни мегабайт, а это можно отсортировать ручками и удалить дубликаты. (sort -u). И так продолжаем - строки на ab, ac.... Так как после удаления дубликатов размер не должен быть больше, то оно вместится. Сами файлы можно сливать в один один побольше время от времени)

Comment: Да не, там же 444 гб, там чего только нет, пароли и логины могут начинаться и на @ и на -

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/968546/178576

Comment: а чтобы снизить количество требуемого для сортировки дискового пространства, файл можно брать «по кусочкам». обработали два куска и получили два отсортированных файла (без дубликатов) — обработайте их как один и получите новый файл (предыдущие можно удалить). берёте следующий кусок исходного файла, обрабатываете совместно с уже накопленным, и так рекурсивно.

Comment: Добавлю классики с `sort | uniq`. Да, ссылку выше я видел.

Answer (score 0):

Я бы написал скрипт на питоне, который построчно выполняет следующие действия:
Берет строку, считает ее хэш, проверяет наличие этого хэша в базе.  Если хэш имеется в базе, то все, переход к следующей строке. Если нет, то добавляет хэш в базу , а строку дописывает к файлу результата. И опять таки переходит к следующей строке.
Небыстро, но довольно просто и наглядно.
Ещё бы можно писать куда нить отдельно текущее смещение или номер строки, чтобы в случае падения скрипта не начинать обработку с самого начала.